# Reading opencv yaml in python gives error "Input file is invalid in function 'open'"

Tags: python, opencv, yaml

I have following test.yaml:

```
Camera.ColourOrder: "RGB"
Camera.ColourDepth: "UCHAR_8"
Camera.Spectrum: "Visible_NearIR"
IMU.T_b_c1: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 4
   cols: 4
   dt: f
   data: [0.999903, -0.0138036, -0.00208099, -0.0202141,
         0.0137985, 0.999902, -0.00243498, 0.00505961,
         0.0021144, 0.00240603, 0.999995, 0.0114047,
         0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

I am trying to read it using python opencv `cv2` module (because it contains opencv related objects like `opencv_matrix` embedded in yaml, which will give error if tried reading using python's inbuilt yaml module). But it is giving me error as shown below:

```
>>> import os
>>> 'test.yaml' in os.listdir()
True
>>> import cv2
>>> fs = cv2.FileStorage("test.yaml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:699: error: (-5:Bad argument) Input file is invalid in function 'open'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: <class 'cv2.FileStorage'> returned a result with an error set
```

I tried removing `IMU.T_b_c1` and keeping just `Camera.xyz` values, still the same error. What I am missing here?

PS: is there any other way / module to read such yaml file with embedded opencv objects? I am ok with not using cv2 and read some other package / module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the error message and [the implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/0052d46b8e33c7bfe0e1450e4bff28b88f455570/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp#L685), OpenCV expects YAML data to be preceded by a YAML directive (`%YAML`). The directive is also shown [in the documentation's sample](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da4/group__core__xml.html).

Try the following (notice first line)

```yaml
%YAML:1.0
Camera.ColourOrder: "RGB"
Camera.ColourDepth: "UCHAR_8"
Camera.Spectrum: "Visible_NearIR"
IMU.T_b_c1: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 4
   cols: 4
   dt: f
   data: [0.999903, -0.0138036, -0.00208099, -0.0202141,
         0.0137985, 0.999902, -0.00243498, 0.00505961,
         0.0021144, 0.00240603, 0.999995, 0.0114047,
         0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Have you tried running by adding `%YAML:1.0`? Is it working on you machine? It is still giving me same error!

Comment: @MsA, No, as I said, judged purely by where the error is coming from in the code. If you search github for the relevant bits and pieces, you'll find prior art like [this](https://github.com/njanirudh/Aruco_Tracker/blob/ccbb4977ee4b02a1b77b2f11de50095042f71b0e/extract_calibration.py#L12) referring to [this](https://github.com/njanirudh/Aruco_Tracker/blob/ccbb4977ee4b02a1b77b2f11de50095042f71b0e/calib_images/test.yaml#L1)

Comment: I dont know whats going on, but now its started working !!